# High performance PHP simaliraty checking on large database

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have 30,000 rows in a database that need to be similarity checked (using `similar_text` or another such function).

In order to do this it will require doing 30,000^2 checks for each columns.

I estimate I will be checking on average 4 columns.

This means I will have to do 3,600,000,000 checks.

What is the best (fastest, and most reliable) way to do this with PHP, bearing in mind request memory limits and time limits etc?

The server need to still actively serve webpages at the same time as doing this.

PS. The server we are using is an 8 core Xeon 32 GB ram.

**Edit:**

The size of each column is normally less that 50 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just need FULL TEXT search.

If that not fits you, you have only one chance to solve this: cache the results.
So you will not have to parse 3bil of records for each requests

Anyway here how you can do it:

```
   $result = array();       

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
   while( $row = ... ) {
      $result[] = $row;    //> Append the current record     
   }
```

Now results contains all the rows from your table.

At this point you said you want to `similar_text()` all columns with each other.
To do that and cache the results you need at least a table (as I said in the comment).

```
   //> Starting calculating the similarity
   foreach($result as $k=>$v) {
      foreach($result as $k2=>$v2) {

           //> At this point you have 2 rows, $v and $v2 containing your column

           $similarity = 0;

           $similartiy += levensthein($v['column1'],$v2['column1']);
           $similartiy += levensthein($v['column2'],$v2['column2']);               
           //> What ever comparison you need here between columns

           //> Now you can finally store the result by inserting in a table the $similarity
           "INSERT DELAYED INTO similarity (value) VALUES ('$similarity')"; 

      }                      
   }
```

2 Things you have to notice:

- I used **levensthein** because it's much faster than similar_text (notice it's value it's the contrary of similar_text, because the greater the value levensthein returns the less the affinity between string)
- I Used **INSERT DELAYED** to greatly lower the database cost

Comment: I'm not really searching, I need to see if 1 column of data is more that 90% similar to any other rows column of data.

Comment: Do you need to compare each column with all the rest? Or you have only 1 string of 1 column that you have to compare with the others?

Comment: Each row's column against each other row's column.

Comment: @petah: is this a task you only need to do once and save somewhere the results or you need to do this more often?

Comment: @yes123, once every now and again. caching will definitely come into play.

Comment: i will post you some code later... if you need to cache results start to create a table to store results

Comment: @Petah: I added the code I would use for this. If you think this answer helped you consider to pick it, thanks.

Comment: @yes123, I did some calulations and running that will take about 2-3 days to complete. (for 30k rows, 4 columns, using levensthein (on a core 2 duo 2.4ghz 2gb ram)), and thats with out the database inserts

Comment: @petah: I think it will not take more than 4-5 hours

Comment: Not the exact answer I was looking for, but the best answer I received.

Comment: Caching in this scenario will require a lot of memory on the server. Most probably you will have to tweak you php settings

Answer (score 0):

oy... similar_text() is O(n^3) !

do you really need a percentage similarity for each comparison or can you just do a quick compare of the first/middle/last X bytes of the strings to narrow the field?

if you're just looking for dups say... you can probably narrow down the number of comparisons you need to do, and that will be the most effective tack imho.